# Check if nested iterator variables sum to a certain number

Tags: java, nested-loops

I want to print an asterisk when `i + j` equals a specified number, but my code never prints one:

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) { 
            for (int j = 5; j < 10; j++) { 
                if ( i == j || ( i+j == 7 )) { 
                    System.out.printf("*"); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.printf(""); 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: "The result is not X"? What does that mean? What is X? Why use `printf` instead of just `print`?

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program? (Hint: Watch the cursor position.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Nothing prints until a newline is written, so the cursor postion is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you are making the blank, it should be a " ", not a "", otherwise there will be no spaces. And it should be if I + J = 14, not 7, as it will never equal 7.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to drawing such patterns is to break them into regions/areas and then use various loops and conditional statements to construct those regions.

E.g. An approach to drawing X pattern is divide the X pattern into two parts from half vertically. Now, you can easily think to draw those to parts.

You can take help from this.

```
public class xpattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalLines = 11;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalLines; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < totalLines; j++) {
                if(i == j || j == (totalLines - (i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }               
            }                       
            System.out.println();
        } 
    }
}
```